# Better techniques for simple tasks

Tags: c#, optimization, styles

So I'm trying to write a fairly large application, one of my first. It accepts quite a lot of input which I need to clean which was fairly simple but I seem to be stuck in a loop of "okay" coding. I would like some help or directions on how I get better at making my tasks more efficient. For example here, an input needs to be checked for 3 things and the code works fine but it just seems like something a pre-schooler would write and I seem stuck doing it as I don't even know where to begin searching for another way. I may need to check upto 40 elements and 40 if statements just seems ridiculous.

```
 bool[] CheckList = new bool[3];

            if (!input.Contains("a"))
            {
                CheckList[0] = true;
            }
            if (!input.Contains("b"))
            {
                CheckList[1] = true;
            }
            if (!input.Contains("c"))
            {
                CheckList[2] = true;
            }

            if (CheckList[0] == true && CheckList[1] == true && CheckList[2] == true)
            {
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
            else
            {
                return "FAILED";
            }
```

What techniques should I look into to adapt my coding style to a more efficient approach, I really doubt this is what professionals are looking for when they are viewing my portfolio. I want to improve.

EDIT: This was just a mockup, the if statement at the end I know can be compacted into one statement. I'm referring more to the if statements, checking conditions. A way of plausibly checking 30-40 conditions without 30+ if statements.

Comment: The first thing you should do is try running your code. If you did that you would have noticed you have an uninitialized identifier and are overflowing your array bounds.

Comment: I wrote the code on stack overflow just to try and make it clear my coding style, the if else type of thing. Not to fix any sorta problem, I fixed it though thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `return new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'}.All(c => input.Contains(c)) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILED";`

Answer (score 1):

Place your chars you want to check into `List` and work with it:

```
var chars = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
return chars.All(g => !input.Contains(g))
    ? "SUCCESS"
    : "FAILED";
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little the coding style here? I'm looking to adapt my coding style to something more well, like this. At the minute my logic is stuck in if else mode.

Comment: @AgritaJD sure, `chars` is a collection of your characters you need to check. Then `All` method is used that returns if all elements from collection satisfy condition. And finally condition - your input should not contain each of the characters from chars collection so `Contains` is used passing `g` which is each element from chars.

Comment: @Roman.Pavelko is using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), [Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) as well as a [Collection Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).